# How to convert Cyrillic letters from uppercase to lowercase or vice versa in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    char upper_cyrillic = 'А';
    std::locale loc("ru_RU.UTF-8");
    char lower_cyrillic = std::tolower(upper_cyrillic, loc);
    std::cout << lower_cyrillic << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried all the options that ChatGPT offered me, but they are all non-working.

Comment: The cyrillic `'А'` in Utf-8 encoding can't be `char`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: It's 1040, but `char` can fit 0...255. Don't ignore complete warnings.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a solution to my problem or something like that?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You should use ICU library when dealing with any kind of non-ascii text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ChatGPT/AI-generated questions are banned.

Comment: @Casey The OP wrote that the question had been posed *to* ChatGPT, not that it had been produced *by* ChatGPT. Questions written by a human are allowed here, even if ChatGPT was given first crack at answering.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an implementation that knows about Cyrillic, and recognizes that name for a locale, you're reasonably close to working code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::locale ru{"ru_RU.UTF-8"};

    std::wcout.imbue(ru);
    std::locale::global(ru);

    auto& facet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(ru);

    std::wstring input = L"Привет, как дела?";

    facet.toupper(input.data(), input.data() + input.size());
    std::wcout << input << L"\n";

    facet.tolower(input.data(), input.data() + input.size());
    std::wcout << input << L"\n";
}
```

Result:

```
ПРИВЕТ, КАК ДЕЛА?
привет, как дела?
```

<kbd>[Test on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c3c932621c0ffb)</kbd>

As a side-note, yes, it probably seems like setting the global locale should be unnecessary (and I'd prefer that it was), but without that it transliterates the result to English characters, so (for example) `'Д'` becomes `'D'`.

As far as UTF-8 encoding goes, you'd normally handle that by converting from UT8-8 to UTF-16 or UTF-32, manipulate that internally, then (if necessary) convert back to UTF-8 for output, something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::locale ru{"ru_RU.UTF-8"};

    std::cout.imbue(ru);
    std::locale::global(ru);

    auto& facet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(ru);

    std::string input = "\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1"
        "\x82\x2c\x20\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\x20\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0"
        "\xbb\xd0\xb0\x3f";

    std::cout << "Mixed case: " << input << "\n";

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring buffer = converter.from_bytes(input);
    
    facet.toupper(buffer.data(), buffer.data() + buffer.size());
   
    std::string upper = converter.to_bytes(buffer);

    std::cout << "Upper case: " << upper << "\n";

    facet.tolower(buffer.data(), buffer.data() + buffer.size());

    std::string lower = converter.to_bytes(buffer);

    std::cout << "Lower case: " << lower << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Mixed case: Привет, как дела?
Upper case: ПРИВЕТ, КАК ДЕЛА?
Lower case: привет, как дела?
```

<kbd>[Test on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905dcc6e73ba4bd5)</kbd>

Tested with gcc 11.3.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: or boost: https://cppsecrets.com/users/143511597102105107104971105048484864103109971051084699111109/C00-boostalgorithmstringtolower.php

Comment: @MarekR • Do the Boost string algorithms work with Russian?  Do they work with UTF-8 encoded strings, or do the strings have to be UTF-16 (or UCS-2) encoded?  (I regret that my experience in C++ is more with Turkish rather than Russian.  Even though I learned Russian in college.  My "go to" answer is ICU.)

Comment: Normally I would post a link to online prove it works, sadly online compilers locale support has been limited (there was time where wandbox and godbolt had multiple locales installed including Russian).

Comment: @MarekR: Here's a test on an online compiler that seems to have the necessary locale support: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d7ad3e60ff8811

Comment: @Eljay: ICU certainly works as well, but seems like overkill in this case, given that the standard library suffices.

Comment: @Eljay here is working boost version: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c3c932621c0ffb (note global locale has to be set).

Comment: Can the standard library suffice for **UTF-8** encoded strings in a `std::string`?  Using either `std` or Boost.  (C++17 if that matters, since `char8_t` landed in C++20.  I already know it works using ICU.)

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, it does. I've added example code for that.

Comment: Thank you for indulging me.  Probably similar to what ICU is doing for me under the covers (I haven't checked).

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, almost certainly. UTF-8 is all right for storage and such, but trying to manipulate it directly is a pain.

Answer (score -1):

`char` is only for "normal" characters. For anything more, research wide characters, unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32.

You can use wide characters, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t upper_cyrillic = L'П';
    wchar_t lower_cyrillic = std::towlower(upper_cyrillic);
    std::wcout << lower_cyrillic << std::endl;
}
```